# Changing RSS title link to link to feed instead of blog

Tags: rss

Frustration!

Is there an easy to change the RSS title link using the RSS widget to link to the feed instead of the blog itself?  It can't be this hard..

I could easily hard code this but I want to keep it as modular as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any easy way in source.

That link is retrieved from feed by SimplePie method and is not passing through any deliberate filters. And it gets concatenated with rest of title after that is passed through filter, not before.

The only idea I have is to filter it in `esc_url()` function at `clean_url` hook, but that will only work nicely if link is unique and won't break elsewhere... Or will take some messy hook juggling to target it precisely.

Comment: Thanks Rarst.  I been looking at the source for a while, and after your response I might as well just hard code something in the template rather than deal with a widget.  I just basically need an rss icon and a title text that link to a feed.  It's crazy WP doesn't have that option or allow you to customize.